# 'NewMasterPAge.SiteMaster' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage'

Tags: c#, web-applications, authentication, master-pages

I am facing this common problem in my application. 
However, As I have seen in other posts, I ensured that my "NewMasterPAge" is a masterpage.
In fact, The first line is: 
**<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.Master.cs" Inherits="NewMasterPAge.SiteMaster" %>**

The problem is occurring when I try to log in with an account and even if I have this problem if I relaunch the site the account I used is logged in.

How can I solve this problem?

I heard of give a "namespace" to every page, but I don't know what this means.

THIS IS THE CODE BEHIND MY MASTER PAGE TEMPLATE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace NewMasterPAge
{
    public partial class aTemplate : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code behind for this master page?

Comment: Actually code behind is something different - this is what is inside `aTemplate.master.cs` file

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner. What is meant by code behind?

Comment: O, I found it. Could you please tell me again what is the code behind that I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded the source code of this project, you have to make these 2 steps:
1. Copy the code from the "MasterPage-Template" and paste it over your actually Site.Master code in your project;
2. Copy the files called "Site.Master.cs" and "Site.Master.designer.cs" from \TailspinSpyworks\Styles and paste them in your project in Site.Master (you can make drag & drop too).